# How do I edit multiple widgets all copied from one widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

From the code below, I'm pulling 6 containers into something like a grid. The problem is that I'm trying to place images in said containers, but I don't know how to. If I edit that container, all 6 would be edited, right?

My `main.dart` page:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'inputpage.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0a0e21),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

First part of the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20 , 20 , 20 , 10),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 35,
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/avatarslika.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code I'm pulling the containers from:

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatefulWidget {
  ReusableCard({required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ReusableCard> createState() => _ReusableCardState();
}

class _ReusableCardState extends State<ReusableCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('You have clicked me');
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 25,
              color: Color(0xd6d6d6d6).withOpacity(0.6),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand you a bit but you can look into gridView in flutter https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Comment: A guy helped me, its ok now..